# Best way to make a VM image from a live Windows laptop

Tags: virtualization, vmware-fusion

I have this Windows laptop and it has some mechanisms to detect the hardware it's running on. I'd like to run it under a VM in my MacBook Air. What's the best way to create a VM from this live machine?

I already own VMware Fusion, so if I could use that for running the VM, it would be the preferred method.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean with *some mechanisms to detect the hardware it's running on* ? Just the regular windows based HW dependency due to installed drivers?

If that is the case you can use [vmware convertor](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) to make a VM out of the windows laptops drive. If you generalize it first you should have no (driver) problems when you boot the image.

Some notes though:

- I do not own or tested it with vmware-fusion (I just got workstation).
- To generalize it you might want to 1) Make a full backup. 2) Test the backup. 3) Sysprep generalise the windows laptop. 4) Convert this driver free windows install to an image. 5) Optionally restore the windows laptop  from the image in step 1.